# Laravel cache - reuse last value when update fails

Tags: php, caching, laravel, laravel-4

We use the cache like this:

```
return Cache::remember('thing', 30, function() {
    return Stuff::getThing();
});
```

If `Stuff::getThing()` throws an exception, this bubbles right up through the app. What I'd like is a way to reuse the last cache value in case of an error. Is there any way to ask Laravel to do this? We can obviously write the logic ourselves by having another failsafe value in the cache that never expires, and returning that if the shorter-lived cache errors, but I was hoping there was a built in way to manage this.

Comment: Ah, I may be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976455/laravel-selective-caching

Comment: If a cached value is not available then there is no cached data at all and you need to take it from `DB`.

Comment: I'm talking about the case where there _was_ cached data 30 minutes ago, but the cache wants to freshen itself now. It would be nice if there was a built-in way to just extend the life of the last value if a new one is available.