# Laravel 8 - Conditionally remember a value in cache

Tags: laravel

I'm using an API for my application. This API doesn't work 100% of the time so I want to cache the queries to reduce the amount of failed results. To this end, I want to use the `Cache::remember()` method.

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$query = ; // the query to be made in the external api

$value = Cache::remember('query-'.Str::slug($query), now()->addWeeks(1), function () use ($query) {
    $baseUrl = ; // the external api's base url
    $response = Http::withHeaders([/* some headers */])->get($baseUrl.$query);

    return ($response->status() !== Response::HTTP_OK) ? false : $response->body();
});
```

However, this will save `false` in the cache for 1 week instead of not saving anything when the query fails.

My second approach is to put everything in a try - catch block and throw an Exception inside the Closure. Is there a better way?

I want `Cache::remember()` to not put anything in the cache if the query fails `($response->status() !== Response::HTTP_OK)` so the next time the code will run, the query is retried.

With the code as it is, `false` will remain in the cache for 1 week so the query won't be retried after it fails.

Comment: You need to explain your desired outcome. What's wrong with the code you have here? I assume you don't want to save `false`?

Comment: Precisely. I don't want to save `false` or anything if it fails.

Comment: Got it. I think your approach of throwing an exception from inside is the only way to avoid storing anything. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976455/laravel-selective-caching

Comment: I'll be using that approach. If you want to, post it as an answer to wrap this question up.